# How to test experimental features in docker 17.06.2-ce

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use --squash option in docker 17.06.2-ce. When I am going to use that feature I got a message saying

> "--squash" is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental
>   features enabled

I have followed tutorial [Docker 1.13 Experimental features](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2017/01/27/docker-1-13-experimental-features/) and issued following commands since I am on ubuntu 16.04.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf 
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --experimental=true
```

Anyway I could not find `docker.conf` file and `docker.service.d` folder. So I have to create those file and folder manually. After that restarted docker deamon issuing following commands.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Anyway Still I get the same message and can't use `squash` option. What I am missing here?

**EDIT**

I have checked docker, issuing following command and found that docker running with experimental enabled.

> sudo docker version

```
Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:59:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run docker command as root with `sudo`, it seems like I can run commands with squash without any issue. Not sure why it gives this incorrect message, instead of permission denied message.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

And add this content:

```
{ 
    "experimental": true 
}
```

Then:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346322/how-to-run-docker-with-experimental-functions-on-ubuntu-16-04)